# Is it possible to cast a long to string in a GENERATE conditional using pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a bunch of longs that are sometimes string "INFINITY" or "NaN". 
Assuming A is a record and B is a long:

I've tried doing...

```
FOREACH A GENERATE (B is not null?B:-1)
```

Though the above is not accurate as sometimes "B" apparently is a string.
Is there some conditional or compound conditional to check if it is not null and either 1) is not a string or 2) cast B such that i can make sure it is not null and does not start with "NaN" in a conditional?

My goal is to make it such that the long gets converted to a number (-1 if it is "NaN", or stay the same if it is not).

Describing A would show the following if exists, (or NaN if does not exist):

{
   "B":28.2524232 
}

Comment: If you use `DESCRIBE A`, what does the relation look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

First load that long data as chararray format, then do conditions on it, then convert back into long. For example,

```
A = load 'data_file' as (B:chararray);
result1 = FOREACH A GENERATE (B matches '(.*)NaN(.*)'?'-1':(B matches '(.*)INFINITY(.*)'?'-1':B)) as B;
result2 = FOREACH result1 GENERATE (long)B;
```

Hope it should work and worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this :

```
FOREACH A GENERATE (B is not null ? (B matches 'NaN' OR B matches 'INFINITY' ? -1 : (int) B):-1)
```

Because of the "NaN" and the "INFINITY" pig may infer a bitearray or chararray, check the DESCRIBE as GoBrewers14 recommend.

Although you can LOAD with a schema and specify it as chararray and then convert as I did it :)

NB : the "B is not null" shouldn't be necessary but in case of ;)